# How to divide gradle sync in Android project

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

we have a huge project and every time the gradle sync is needed takes too much time.

I would like to know best practice to divide the gradle sync or how can we break sync down in order to be faster.

If anyone may help me it would be very usefull.
Thanks in advance,

Comment: What do you mean by "divide the gradle sync"? Take a look at this guide to identify performance problems in your build setup and fix them: https://gradle.github.io/performance-guide/

Comment: I am pretty sure that this tutorial will help me out. Regarding what you mentioned about "divide gradle sync" is the following. The project is a legacy one and there is a lot of third party libs and many flavours. So the each gradle task is executed many many but many time and it may takes up to 30 minutes or more and it is in my opinion unacceptable. I just would like a way to avoid all this stuffs and only sync the part i need but first i believe it is required to restructure the gradle structure and that the point I created this post. If you have any other tips I would thank you.

Comment: I think it's hard to provide suggestions without seeing your actual project structure, but I'm pretty sure that the guide I linked will answer most of your questions.

Comment: I will post my gradle structure later and let you know. I understand thats difficult without know its structure but I think if I post it here will provide you more info and this will help you to help me out. :D
Thanks for all info you provided so far!

Comment: Sorry, but I don't think I'll have time to go through your project structure if you publish it. I'd suggest that you start optimizing it on your own, and in case you have any specific problems you can't solve on your own - please open another question and I'll be happy to take a look at it.